# Criei uma página parallax e estou tentando fixar o Menu para acompanhar na rolagem da página , mas quando coloco o nav com a opsição fixer ele some

Tags: html, css, parallax

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    color:#242424;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #fff;
}

.wrapper{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

main{
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 760px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

section.module p{
margin-bottom: 40px;
}

section.module:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

section.module h2{
    margin-bottom:40px;
    font-size:30px;
}

section.module.content{
    padding:40px 0 ;
    background-color: #b08968;
}

section.module.parallax{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   height: 100vh !important; 
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover ;
   -webkit-background-size:cover

}

section.module.parallax:after{
    content:"";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 8;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%, #000 100%); 
}

section.module.parallax-1{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/18/89/L2YNZA.jpg");
}

section.module.parallax-2{
    background-image: url("https://images.alphacoders.com/551/thumb-1920-551056.jpg");
}

section.module.parallax-3{
    background-image: url("https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/smite-x-aang-avatar-4k_bGZsZ2iUmZqaraWkpJRqZmdlrWdtbWU.jpg");
}

section.module.parallax h1{
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 78px;
    z-index: 50;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

.menu{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color:#b08968;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;

    
}

.menu-link{
    padding:18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#b08968;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    
    
}

.menu-link:hover{
    color: bisque;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estio.css">
</head>









<body>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <main>
            <nav class="menu">
                <a href="#" class="menu-link">Avatar Aang  </a>    
                 <a href="#" class="menu-link">sobre </a>    
                 <a href="#" class="menu-link">overview </a>      
                 <a href="#" class="menu-link">netflix </a>    
            </nav>
        
            <section class="module parallax parallax-1">
               
                <h1>A lenda de Aang </h1>
            </section>

            <section class="module content">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Como foi criada ?</h2>
                    <p>
                        Avatar: A Lenda de Aang é uma série animada co-criada e produzida por Michael Dante DiMartino e Bryan Konietzko na Nickelodeon Animation Studios, em Burbank, Califórnia. A série possui um total de 61 episódios. Em 21 de julho de 2010, Brown Johnson, presidente da Nickelodeon, 
                        anunciou que o canal começou a produzir em seus estúdios, uma continuação da série.
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        O sucessor a nova versão é A Lenda de Korra, estreou nos Estados Unidos
                         em 14 de abril de 2012 e já foi finalizada em 19 de dezembro de 2014, contando com 4 temporadas.
                    </p>


                </div>

            </section>
            <section class="module parallax parallax-2"> 
                    <h1> Overview </h1>
            </section>

            
            <section class="module content">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Overview da animação:</h2>
                    <p>
                        A série conta as aventuras de Aang, o então sucessor de uma longa linhagem de avatares. Ele e seus amigos Katara, Sokka, e mais tarde Toph Beifong, 
                        têm a missão de salvar o mundo dos ataques da Nação do Fogo, que tem como objetivo o domínio de todo o mundo.                    </p>

                    <p>
                        A série encontra-se estruturada sob a forma de "livros", onde cada episódio é um "capítulo" e cada temporada um "livro" diferente. A sua estreia foi planejada para novembro de 2004, mas foi transmitida pela primeira vez no dia 21 de Fevereiro de 2005 no canal Nickelodeon dos 
                        Estados Unidos da América. O último episódio da série foi exibido a 19 de julho de 2008.
                    </p>


                </div>

            </section>

            <section class="module parallax parallax-3">
                <h1> Live Action: Netflix </h1>
            </section>

            <section class="module content">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Anúncio do live action: Netflix</h2>
                    <p>
                        Há cerca de 3 anos, a Netflix anunciou que estaria trabalhando em uma adaptação live-action de Avatar: A Lenda de Aang. Na época, a produção foi descrita como uma reimaginação do desenho, e supostamente começaria a ser produzida em 2019. Desde então, a série parece ter passado por alguns momentos conturbados, principalmente dada a saída dos criadores do desenho. Foi apenas neste ano que recebemos novidades sobre a obra, 
                        que finalmente conta com um elenco anunciado e parece estar novamente encaminhada para tomar forma.                    </p>


                </div>

            </section>


            
        </main>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: posta também o código HTML, apenas com o CSS não temos como validar o que está tentando fazer.

Comment: Postei agora , dá uma olhadinha.

Answer (score -1):

Para resolver  o problema basta adicionar a propriedade z-index com valor 51 para a classe .menu, dessa forma:

.menu {z-index: 51;}

Com isso o menu ficará na frente de todos os elementos.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).